# Can `co_yield` return a value from the caller on resumption of the coroutine?

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20

C++20 introduces coroutines, which can be used to create generators and other similar things:

```
generator<int> counter(int max) {
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        co_yield i;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to create a coroutine such that the caller can provide a response that is returned by `co_yield` once the coroutine is resumed? Let's call this a `channel` instead of a generator.

This is an example of what I want to be able to do:

```
channel<int, int> accumulator(int initial) {
    while(true) {
        // Can channel be written so co_yield provides a response?
        int response = co_yield initial;
        initial += response;
    }
}
```

Here, whenever the caller resumes the coroutine, it would provide a value which then gets returned from `co_yield` once the coroutine is resumed, like so:

```
std::vector<int> accumulate(std::vector<int> values) {
    channel<int, int> acc = accumulator(0);

    std::vector<int> summed_values;

    for(int v : values) {
        // Get whatever value was yielded by the accumulator
        int sum = acc.recieve();
        // Do something with the value
        summed_values.push_back(sum);
        // Resume the accumulator, returning this value from co_yield:
        acc.send(v); 
    }
    return summed_values;
}
```

#### Edit based on comment

Can anyone provide some guidance or an example on how to do this? Coroutines are still very new to me. I have a bare-bones implementation of a `channel` class, but I'm not sure what should be returned from `yield_value` in order to achieve this.

The two locations in question I've marked `(A)` and `(B)` in the comments.

```
template <class Out, class In>
struct channel {
    struct promise_type {
        Out current_value;
        auto yield_value(Out value) {
            current_value = value;
            // (A) What do I return here?
        }
        channel get_return_object() {
            return {std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)};
        }
        // We run up until the first value is ready
        auto initial_suspend() noexcept { return std::suspend_never(); }
        auto final_suspend() noexcept { return std::suspend_always(); }
        void unhandled_exception() noexcept { std::terminate(); }
    };


    Out receive() {
        return handle.promise().current_value;
    }
    void send(In response) {
        // (B) What do I do here?
    }
    // Constructors, destructor and move assignment operator omitted for brevity
   private:
    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: Yes. The return value of `co_yield v` is the return value of `co_await p.yield_value(v)` where `p` is the coroutine promise. So the caller can call a custom method on the promise (you called it `send`) to feed a value back into the coroutine, and the `yield_value()` method returns an awaiter that spits out that value.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Could you give me some guidance on the implementation? I've updated the question to include what I have so far! There are just two locations I've marked A and B which I'm not sure how to fill in

Comment: `send` can use `handle.promise()` to access the `promise_type` and put the value in a new promise member variable. `yield_value` then returns an awaiter that produces that value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is `await_resume`, which is called on the awaiter (result of `yield_value`) to obtain the result of `co_yield`.

You also need to store the response *somewhere*. As Raymond Chen suggested in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354960/can-co-yield-return-a-value-from-the-caller-on-resumption-of-the-coroutine#comment110281142_62354960), you can put the value in a new data member of `promise_type`.

So changes are:

1. Add a data member to `promise_type`.

   ```
   In response;
   ```
2. Define a customized awaiter to return that data member.

   ```
   struct awaiter : std::suspend_always {
       friend promise_type;
       constexpr In await_resume() const { return m_p->response; }

   private:
       constexpr awaiter(promise_type* p) : m_p(p) {}
       promise_type* m_p;
   };
   ```
3. In `(A)`, return the customized awaiter.

   ```
   return awaiter(this);
   ```
4. In `(B)`, set the data member, then resume the coroutine.

   ```
   handle.promise().response = response;
   handle.resume();
   ```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you!